# Data validation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on integrating data validation into a table schema in SQL Server 2014.

- Column `smoke` can contain 0 (non-smoker), 1 (smoker) or 9 (missing).
- Column `cigarette` can be a value equal to or under 887, 888 (not applicable) or 999 (missing).

I want SQL Server to throw an error if a value other then not-applicable (888) or missing (999) is inserted into `cigarette` if `smoking` contains 0 (non-smoker). How do I do this?

This is an example of what I have now:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CHECK_table]
(
    [study_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [smoke] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [cigarettes] [smallint] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CHECK_table] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CHECK (([smoke] = (0) OR ([smoke] = (1) OR [smoke] = (8)) OR [smoke] = (9)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CHECK_table] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CHECK (([cigarettes] <= (90) OR [cigarette] = (888) OR [cigarette] = (999)))
GO
```

Comment: Why are you not using NULL when the value is not known. You are using a forced value to represent NULL. This seems overly complicated and difficult to work with. For example. The column smoke could become IsSmoker and store it as a bit. The possible values then ore NULL, 0 and 1.

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you for your comment. The data is coded this way for use in statistical programs, null is not used. I have to check the data according to the coding that was used (9=missing) and be able to export it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` and replace multiple `OR` to `IN`:

```
CREATE TABLE #CHECK_table(
  [study_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
  [smoke] [smallint] NOT NULL,
  [cigarettes] [smallint] NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE #CHECK_table 
WITH CHECK ADD CHECK ([smoke] IN (0,1,9));

ALTER TABLE #CHECK_table 
WITH CHECK ADD CHECK (((CASE WHEN [smoke] = 0 AND [cigarettes] IN(999,888) THEN 1
                             WHEN [smoke] <> 0 AND ([cigarettes] <= 888 
                                                   OR [cigarettes] = 999) THEN 1
                            ELSE 0 END) = 1)
                     );
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/451564)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

As expressed in one of the comments, Why not just let them be `NULL` for unknown data?  If you use a nullable bit field, you can get the same amount of detail you'd get by your scheme, with better storage and performance, and no need to enforce any constraints.

My suggestion:

```
CREATE TABLE #CHECK_table(
  [study_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
  [smoke] [bit] NULL,
  [cigarettes] [smallint] NULL ,
    check (( case when [smoke] = 0 then 0 else 1 end ) = 1)
   )

insert into #check_table ( study_id, smoke, cigarettes ) select 1, 1, 12
insert into #check_table ( study_id, smoke, cigarettes ) select 1, 0, 12
insert into #check_table ( study_id, smoke, cigarettes ) select 1, 1, null
```

The second insert there will fail with an error about the insert conflicting with the check constraint.

<del>(aside: And also, why are you using `smallint` - do you not expect to see very many records?)</del>

**add:**

For export, when doing your final select from your table (as above), you could do:

```
select  [study_id],
    cast(case when [smoke] is null then 9 else [smoke] end as smallint) as [smoke],
    [cigarettes]
from    #CHECK_table
```

That way, you'd have clean data in your tables, without any codification.  From a data standpoint, it's much clearer what you're seeing when you look at a bit column - it's either yes, no, or hasn't been answered.  This also means that it's clear, when looking through the code, exactly *that* you've been codifying the data as well as *how* you've codified it.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your suggestion. study_id is a foreign key for data about studies in another table, this is not mentioned in my example. Please see my other comment about not using null.

Comment: The distinction between not-applicable and missing has to be made, so a 0,1,null is not sufficient. I agree that your solution is better if there was no need for a not-applicable value.

Comment: I guess it's down to preference, at this point.  I'd only code the data if it were needed, rather than coding it in the data store.  Coding it for use in SPSS or something, sure, run a query that codes it.  But I wouldn't code the data according to what SPSS wants to see whilst storing the data, as the data must be interpretable by other tools, at other times, rather than being stored in something which is specific to a particular tool.